# Black iOS launch screen instead of white

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I have an issue with changing background color of launch screen on iOS. When I open the app for the first time it loads a white page before the black `viewcontroller` appears. How can I change the white launch screen to a black one?

Below is my app General launch image settings:

[image]

I am still new with iOS. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a launch image selected for your launchscreen. Is this image white or black ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create a launch screen storyboard and select that as launch screen file.

[image]

Then change the background to black. You can also customize it whatever way you want

[image]

Comment: For those wondering, this page is called the  Interface Builder.

Answer (score 7):

There are many scenario about LaunchScreen turns into black.

Here another scenario which I experienced it.

If you set background color of **LaunchScreen.storyboard** from **"New Color Set"** from **Assets.xcassets** then it turns into back.

Use SystemColor or Custom RBG Value to your **LaunchScreen.storyboard**
Issue Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before. The default launch screen color is 'system background color' and it will be black when dark mode is enabled. If you prefer to use white background color all the time, you can simply switch to white color in your panel.

[image]

Comment: What if I want to use a custom color for DarkMode?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, my case was on React Native, but it is no different for creating an iOS launch screen, the reason for the black screen was creating a `storyboard` file instead of `Launch Screen`, I have deleted my last file that I created and then try to create Launch Screen by the below option:

[image]

I don't know what was the main reason because in `setting > general` the launch screen setting was correct but still I was facing the black screen, I deleted and re-create everything by using the above image and it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Found a much easier and cleaner approach if you really just want a color as Launch Screen in 2023.

1. Define your preferred color in your Assets e.g. as AccentColor
   [image: asset]
2. Add "Background color" as String in you plist with the name of your color as value
   [image: plist]
3. Done